# calculator using radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, radio-button, calculator

I'm trying to make a simple calculator using radio buttons in `asp.net` and `c#`. Two numbers are entered into a textbox each and a submit button is clicked and entered into a label.
The error I get is when the radio button is checked and submit is clicked, I get a runtime error; can anyone please help diagnose why?

This is my code:

```
int total;

if (rbAdd.Checked)
{
    total = Convert.ToInt32(tbNo1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(tbNo2.Text);
    lblAns2.Text = total.ToString();
}

if (rbMult.Checked)
{
    total = Convert.ToInt32(tbNo1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(tbNo2.Text);
    lblAns2.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You could simplify your code. Parse the numbers at the beginning by using `int.TryParse` which also prevents errors. Then sum or multiply accordingly and assign the result at the end. Otherwise you have unnecessary code duplication which makes it difficult to understand and to maintain your code.

Comment: Please also add the code for your submit button and the OnClick Event.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified code that still fails the same way:

```
int total = 0;

int no1 = Convert.ToInt32(tbNo1.Text);
int no2 = Convert.ToInt32(tbNo2.Text);
if (rbAdd.Checked)
{
    total = no1 + no2;
}
else if (rbMult.Checked)
{
    total = no1 * no2;
}
lblAns2.Text = total.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and I got error message(`Input string was not in a correct format.`) only whenever I enter non integer values, because of your convert code `Convert.ToInt32(tbNo1.Text);`.

Do you want the entered values to be only integer? If so, please try this code instead (Modified from **John Saunders** code):

```
int total = 0;
int no1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(decimal.Parse(tbNo1.Text), 0));
int no2 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(decimal.Parse(tbNo2.Text), 0));
if (rbAdd.Checked)
{
    total = no1 + no2;
}
else if (rbMult.Checked)
{
    total = no1 * no2;
}
lblAns2.Text = total.ToString();
```

You also have to validate the entered values as well to protect invalid characters.

Otherwise if you don't need to convert the entered values to be integer you could use this code:

```
decimal total = 0;
decimal no1 = decimal.Parse(tbNo1.Text);
decimal no2 = decimal.Parse(tbNo2.Text);
if (rbAdd.Checked)
{
    total = no1 + no2;
}
else if (rbMult.Checked)
{
    total = no1 * no2;
}
lblAns2.Text = total.ToString();
```